# Periodic work runs only when application is running in Android API 28

Tags: android, android-workmanager, notificationmanager

I tested the same code in API level 24 and 28. With API 24 it shows notifications every half an hour no matter if application is in the background or foreground or even stopped. But with API 28 it only shows notifications every half an hour when application is in the foreground. When app is in the background it shows notifications at random long intervals. When application is stopped it never shows notifications. How do I create application which shows regular notifications in new versions of Android? I tried to use WorkManger and NotificationManagerCompat. WorkManager version is latest 2.2.0.  Code which I tested is simple, I got it from oficial documentation:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id_1"
    }

    class MyWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) 
        : Worker(context, workerParams ) { 

        override fun doWork(): Result {
            var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle("notificattion")
                .setContentText("notification")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notify(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 1000), builder.build())
            }

            return Result.success()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        createNotificationChannel()

        val myWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "MyUniqueWorkName",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, myWork)
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channel mine", importance).apply {
                description = "description"
            }
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What devices are you running on?  Can you reproduce this on emulators?